# Use Zurb in a git repo with latest components

Tags: git, github, components, zurb-foundation

I've installed the Zurb Foundation framework in one of my git repos. What's the best way to keep using the latest scss components?

Git submodule? Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

After a few weeks of working with Zurb I now realise the answer is...

**gemfile**

Zurb offer the gem for [exactly this purpose](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html). You can still include the components you want, and update to the latest release using:

`gem update zurb-foundation`

However, I've found I do need to regularly consult the [scss folder in the repo](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/tree/master/scss/foundation/components) in order to figure out how styles and mixins are being applied.

Comment: In version 5 Zurb now uses Bower to handle updates: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html